# How to create a function f(x,y) = z where an increase in |x-y| corresponds with an increase z and |y| corresponds with decrease in z

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm trying to figure out a function that does the following:

1. Increases with `a` (that is, the absolute value of the magnitude between `x` and `y`)
2. Decreases when `b` increases (the absolute value of `y`)
3. Scales the resulting value `z` between the closed interval `[0,1]`

`x` can be any value between `[-2, 2]`
`y` can be any value between `[-2,2]`

```
a = |x - y|
b = |y|
z = # How can I manipulate `a` and `b`?
```

For example, the best case scenario would be the following (highest `z` value):

**Case 1:**

$$ x \subset \{-2,2\} $$

$$ y = 0 $$

$$ z = 1 $$

The worst case scenario would be the following (lowest `z` value):

**Case 2:**

$$ x \subset \{-2, 2\} $$
$$ y = x $$
$$ z = 0 $$

My thoughts were to do the following:

```
z = |x - y|/|y|

Case 1: |2 - 0|/0 = infinity
Case 2: |2 - 2|/2 = 0
```

If I went with this approach, how would I set a limit for Case 1 to approach 1 instead of infinity?

but I would need to scale my infinity down to 1 so limits might be the answer.

Comment: I think you need to write this mathematically and get rid of the python if it is to belong on this site. It is really not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Apologies, I just rephrased the question and removed the programming language references.

Comment: It still does not make sense though. If you have a function $z=f(x,y)$. Then $|x-y|$ and $|y|$ are already determined so cannot be maximised or minimised. I think what you mean is a function $(u,v,w)=f(x,y)$ and you are interested in maximising/minimising $|u-v|$ and $|v|$.

Comment: In the case you mentioned above, what would the quantity `w` be?

Comment: I have no idea. Whatever your $z$ is. But as it is your question does not make sense.

Comment: I'm sorry it's not formulated correctly.  Right now with `z = |x - y|/|y|` if I have `x=2, y=0` then `z = infinity`.  Is there anything I can do to adjust `z = |x-y|/|y|` so that a value of `infinity` equals `1` instead?

Comment: If you want a scaling between $0$ and $1$ you could have $z=\frac{|a-b|}{|a|+|b|}$. Still unsure on what the max/min means though.

Comment: My use of `maximizing` and `minimizing` are poor terms.  What I meant to say was that I would like an increase in `a` correspond with an increase in `z` while an increase in `b` corresponds with a decrease in `z`.  Essentially, I am trying to create a score that favors large differences between `x` and `y` but favors lower values of `y`.

Comment: Yes, the only correction is that $a \in [0,4]$ because $x \in [-2,2]$ and $y \in [-2,2]$ therefore $a$ can be $|2 - (-2)|$ in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for updating the comments/answers.  I think I might be missing a key detail here: https://i.imgur.com/bV6jZZA.png I have the following function $z = f(x,y)$ and with the above equation when $x=2, y=0$ the output is $z=0.333$ when it's expected to be $0$ . Which part did I misinterpret?

EDIT: `a_coef` and `b_coef` should be called `a_power` and `b_power`.  I'll try to be more careful with using the correct terminology.

Comment: You should rewrite your question so it actually makes sense. And get rid of the max / min terminology as it is completely unrelated. Perhaps also include some reason behind the question. Almost all of what you have in the current version is unnecessary.

Comment: The highest possible score would be when $ \subset \{−2,2\}$ and $=0$ because $=|−|$ would be at the maximum (I believe that is the correct term in this case) and $=||$ would be at its lowest possible value. Does this make sense or am I lost in my own logic?

EDIT: I've updated my question to fix the terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing the comments, the question you are asking is to find a function $z(a,b)\in[0,1]$ where $a=|x-y|$, $b=|y|$, $x,y\in[-2,2]$. You further want this function to have the property that an increase with $a$ corresponds with an increase in $z$ and a decrease in $b$ corresponds with an increase in $z$.

Any function $z(a,b)=\frac{f(a)}{g(b)}$ where $0\le f(a) \le g(b)$ and $f$ and $g$ are monotone inreasing will have the required properties. If we set $f(a)=a=|x-y|\le |y|+|x| \le b+2$ then we see that $g(b)=b+2$ is a valid choice. So the obvious consideration is
$$ z=\frac{a}{b+2}.$$
If you want disproportionate weights on changes in either $a$ or $b$ or for $z$ to favor "low" or "high" values there is a lot of wiggle room in choosing $f$ and $g$.

To give an example of an alternate option suppose you wanted $f(a)=a^2$ and you wanted $g(b)$ to be a degree lower (so that $z$ grows faster with $a$ than the correspondent decrease with $b$). We have that
$$ a^2 = |x-y|^2 = x^2 + y^2 -2xy = x^2 + y(y-2x) \le 4 + 6b.$$
Therefore
$$z=\frac{a^2}{6b+4}$$
also works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience with my terminology and helping me work through my thought process.

Comment: I'm diving into the details of your answer and had a question for the $f(a) = a ... b+2$ line.  I understand why $ 0 ≤ f(a) ≤ g(b) $ and why $f$ and $g$ must increase monotonically. I also understand when you set $f(a) = a = | x + y | ≤ |y| $ but I'm confused on why you add the $|y| + |x|$.  Where does the $+|x|$ come from?

Comment: My understanding of this is that the maximum values for $|x|$ and $|y|$ are 2.  Hence, $b + 2$.  Is this correct?

Comment: But I never wrote that. I have $f(a)=a=|x-y|\le |y|+|x| \le b+2$