# Understanding $z(a,b) \in[0,1]$ where $a=|x-y|$, $b=|y|$ and $x,y\in[-2,2]$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations, functional-calculus

I previously asked [a poorly written question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3836635/how-to-create-a-function-fx-y-z-where-an-increase-in-x-y-corresponds-with) that used incorrect terminology.  A user [@epiliam](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/765629/epiliam) was very patient and worked me through my logic to understand what I was trying to ask.  I had a question about understanding some of the details of their answer.

In particular, I was looking for a function $z(a,b)\in[0,1]$ where $a=|x-y|$, $b=|y|$, $x,y\in[-2,2]$. The desired function would have the property that an increase with $a$ corresponds with an increase in $z$ and a decrease in $b$ corresponds with an increase in $z$.

The answer from @epiliam quoted here:

> Any function $z(a,b)=\frac{f(a)}{g(b)}$ where $0\le f(a) \le g(b)$ and $f$ and
> $g$ are monotone inreasing will have the required properties. If we
> set $f(a)=a=|x-y|\le |y|+|x| \le b+2$ then we see that $g(b)=b+2$ is a
> valid choice. So the obvious consideration is  $$ z=\frac{a}{b+2}.$$
> If you want disproportionate weights on changes in either $a$ or $b$
> or for $z$ to favor "low" or "high" values there is a lot of wiggle
> room in choosing $f$ and $g$.
>
> To give an example of an alternate option suppose you wanted
> $f(a)=a^2$ and you wanted $g(b)$ to be a degree lower (so that $z$
> grows faster with $a$ than the correspondent decrease with $b$). We
> have that $$ a^2 = |x-y|^2 = x^2 + y^2 -2xy = x^2 + y(y-2x) \le 4 +
> > 6b.$$ Therefore $$z=\frac{a^2}{6b+4}$$
> also works.

I understand why $0 \le f(a) \le g(b)$ and why $f$ and $g$ must be monotone increasing to fill these properties and to ensure $z \in[0,1]$ .

In the answer, the most simple solution was to set $f(a) = a = |x + y|$.  In doing so, $g(b)$ was set to $|y| + |x| \le b + 2$.

**My questions in trying to understand how $g(b)$ is calculated given $f(a)$:**

1. Why does the $g(b)$ in $0 \le f(a) \le g(b)$ turn into $|y| + |x| \le b + 2$ when $f(a) = a = |x + y|$?

$b + 2$ makes sense from $|y| + |x|$ since $b = |y|$.

2. Is $|x| = 2$ because the maximum magnitude for $x = 2$ while the greatest value $a$ can be is 4** (e.g. $x=2, y=-2$ so $|2 - (-2)|$) and $f(a) \le g(b)$?
3. Similarly, when $f(a) = a^2 = |x - y|^2 = (x - y)(x - y) = x^2 + y^2 - 2xy$ how would one calculate that $g(b) = 4 + 6b$?

In this case, if I fill in the maximum values for this where $x=2, y=-2$ then $f(a(2,-2)) = 2^2 + (-2)((-2) + (-2)(2)) = 4 + (-2)*(-6))$ which feels like it's getting close to the answer.

I don't entirely understand if one was to do this from the beginning, how would you come up with $g(b)$ given $f(a)$.

If this is poorly formatted or phrase, please let me know.  I will make the changes immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z(a,b)\in [0,1]$, then we have $z(a,b)\leq 1.$ Then $b=|y|$ and because $x\in[-2,2]$ we have that $x\leq 2$, or $|x|\leq 2$.

By the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) we have $$f(a)=a=|x-y|\color{red}{\leq}|x|+|y|\leq b+2$$

This means that $$a=f(a)\leq b+2$$

or $$\frac{a}{b+2}=\frac{f(a)}{b+2}\leq 1$$

so choosing $g(b)=b+2$ we indeed have found a function $z(a,b)$ with $$z(a,b)=\frac{f(a)}{g(b)}=\frac{a}{b+2}\leq 1$$

that also satisfies the required properties.

Comment: Thank you.  I've upvoted your answer.  I've updated my question to make it a bit more specific.  Regarding your answer, I was under the assumption that $g(b)$ meant that $g$ was only dependent on $y$ but in reality it's actually dependent on $x$ and $y$.  Is this correct?

Comment: No $g$ is only dependent on $y$ since we have $g(b)=2+b=2+|y|$. We have used that $x\in [-2,2]$ to bound $|x|.$

Comment: Ok, that makes sense WHY $g(b) = |x| + |y| = 2 + b$ but I guess I'm still a bit confused on why it was obvious to think of adding $|x|$ in the first place.  Apologies, I'm sure the answer is obvious but I'm trying to extend this logic to the case where $f(a) = a^2$ and I get a bit lost on the steps to find $g(b)$.

Comment: $g(b)=|x|+|y|$ is not correct, we've chosen $g(b)=2+b$ with no $x$ dependence. $f(a)=a=|x-y|$ depends on both $x$ and $y$ and using this information and the triangle inequality we arrived that $a=f(a)\leq |x|+|y|\leq 2+|y|=2+b.$ The term $ |x|+|y|$ is just used as a "step", so that we could use the bound $|x|\leq 2$ and arrive at $2+b$.

Comment: If instead you choose $f(a)=a^2$, then from above we arrive at $a^2=x^2+y(y-2x)$. Now since $x\leq 2$, then $x^2\leq 4$. Then $y-2x\leq 6$ since $-2x\in[-4,4]$ and $y\in[-2,2]$ so adding these two we have $y-2x\in[-6,6]$ (so we can see it is bounded above by $6$). Together with $|y|=b$ we have $$x^2+y(y-2x)\leq 4+6b.$$ And again we take $g(b)=4+6b$ in this case which satisfies the required properties.

Comment: Note we could have used the previous part here instead. Since we have $a\leq b+2$ then $a^2\leq (b+2)^2=b^2+4b+4=4+b(b+4)$ and since $|y|\leq 2$ we have $b=|y|\leq 2$ so $$a^2\leq 4+b(b+4)\leq 4 +b(2+4)=4+6b.$$

Comment: That makes much more sense coming from $a^2 \le (b + 2)^2$.  We know that $b = |y|$ and that $|y| \le 2$ so $b = |y| \le 2$.  Then for $f(2,-2)$ we get $|x-y|^2 \le (2 - (-2))^2 = 16 \le g(b(y=-2)) = 4 + |-2|(|-2| + 4) = 4 + -2*-6 = 16$.  The only part that I'm still not entirely clear on is why we fill in the upper bound of $b$ on $(b + 4)$ and leave the $b$ outside the parentheses.  I know I'm missing a key piece here but I feel like I almost understand it.

Comment: Since $a^2\leq 4+b(b+4)$, you can have $g(b)=4+b(b+4)$ if you want, but now we have $b^2$ and $b$ to work with. For convenience, we used the upper bound on $b+4$ to obtain $a^2\leq 4+6b$, so we can take $g(b)=4+6b$ instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm getting it now. $g(b) = 4 + b(b+4)$ would work but we want to simplify it and remove the quadratic. For an upper bound with $x=2, y=-2$ and the fact that $z \in[0,1]$, then $g(b) = 4 + b(b+4)$ could be simplified by using  $a^2 = 16$ at the upper bound and setting $(b+4) = 6$ so that $g(2) = 4 + 2*6 = 16$.  Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: Since we have the upper bound $b=y\leq 2$, $g(b)=4+b(b+4)$ can be simplified by setting $b=2$ in $b+4$, this gives $b+4=6$. Then we have $g(b)=4+6b$. In this case we have $f(a)=a^2$ so $$z=\frac{f(a)}{g(b)}=\frac{a^2}{4+6b}.$$

Comment: This satisfies the required properties and also we've shown above that $a^2\leq 4+6b$, thus $z\leq 1$.

Comment: I accepted your answer.  Thanks for your patience in breaking this down for me.  Is there a field of math that this belongs in that I can get more familiar with? This type of math seems extremely versatile.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a specific field related to this. Since it's finding functions that satisfy given properties and using bounds, I would say it's related algebra and analysis.